# Rails: Mainpulate Image After Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, imagemagick, rmagick

In a Rails environment, I want to manipulate an image after it has been uploaded. I do not need to change the image, but I want to present it to the user based on parameters in the URL.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add the different ways in which you'd like to present the image?

Comment: I would like to add some text to an image based on parameters in the url. Specifically, have a gift certificate that I want to imprint with a value and a verification code. 

I have a solution, but it saves the image file each time. It's what you would expect in that I call a helper method from the view (in the path param of image_tag) that does some image processing, saves the file, and returns the path to the saved file.

Answer (score 0):

It means after uploading completed you need to show image, you can show imaged using javascript and jquery, i have done this in sample project like following way

```
function showThumbnail(files){
            for(var i=0;i< files.length;i++){
                var file = files[i];
                var imageType = /image.*/
                if(!file.type.match(imageType)){
                    alert("Not an image");
                }
                var image = document.createElement("img");
                var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
                image.file = file;
                if(file.type.match(imageType)) {
                    if((thumbnail.hasChildNodes() == true)){
                        thumbnail.removeChild(thumbnail.firstChild);
                        thumbnail.appendChild(image);
                    }else
                    {
                        thumbnail.appendChild(image);
                    }
                }
                var reader = new FileReader()
                reader.onload = (function(aImg){
                    return function(e){
                        aImg.src = e.target.result;
                    };
                }(image))
                var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                image.onload= function(){
                    ctx.drawImage(image,75,75);
                    $(".uploadedPhoto").addClass('whiteBG');
                    $(".uploadtxt").html(file.name);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not very Railsy. This may be a good answer, but I was hoping for a server-side solution. I realize now that that might not be possible, and a javascript solution is the only way to do what I want to do.

I have a server-side solution where the new file gets saved, but that is not what I asked to do. I will accept this answer if someone tells me it works.